# How do I tell Rails to Allow a Column to have Arrays instead of Strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a migration I do:

```
add_column :users, :roles, :string, default: "member"
```

But I wish for it to return an array. As an example, I could run this code:

```
def user_role_rules
  return [] if @user.roles.nil?
  @user.roles.each do |role|
    exec_role_rules(role) if @user.roles.include?(role)
  end
end
```

Being ignorant of `@user` and other methods, we'll assume this code runs if `@user.roles` returns `# => ["member"]`, but instead it will return `# => "member"`. This causes the each to error out with the message: `undefined method 'each' for "member":String`. Is there a way to have `@user.roles` to return an array instead of a string?

Comment: Why don't you create a new table `Role` and set up `belongs-to`-`has_many` association b/w `Role`-`User`. This way, a `@user.roles` will always return the array of user's designated roles.

Comment: Trying not to do this as I'm working with a gem that decided that this was not the way to go.

Comment: I think I'll just fork the repo, create a new branch, and submit a new PR if the role is a string and with ruby push it into an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
add_column :users, :roles, :string, array: true
```

Comment: Didn't know this existed! Have you got any documentation references?

Comment: It doesn't for me. When running `rake db:migrate` I received: `StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Unknown key: :array. Valid keys are: :unique, :order, :name, :where, :length, :internal, :using, :algorithm`

Comment: That might be why it is not working for you. MySQL is missing a lot of features compared to PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to migrate the column to a text column instead of a string column.

Then in the model put this:

```
serialize :roles, Array
```

Comment: Is passing `Array` class necessary there? Doesn't `serialize` handles that for primitive classes by itself?

Comment: @kiddorails I have no idea mate. Why don't you try and then either post an answer or edit mine.

Comment: Getting an error where I can't provide a default value for text. Do you know a way around this when creating a role for a user?

Comment: @BenMorganIO Try providing `default: nil`. It's probably because you've already had a default in that column. That's why it's not behaving as clean as if you just created the column from scratch. At worst, just drop the column and create a new one.